# 2 Related Questions About Finding A Closed Form

Tags: combinatorics, recursion, catalan-numbers

1. Consider the sequence defined by
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   s_0=0\\
   s_1=3\\
   s_n=6s_{n-1}-9s_{n-2} & \text{if }n\ge 2
   \end{cases}
   .$$
   Find a closed form for $s_n$.

---

2. Consider the sequence defined by
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   t_0=5\\
   t_1=9\\
   t_n=6t_{n-1}-9t_{n-2} & \text{if }n\ge 2
   \end{cases}
   .$$
   Find a closed form for $t_n$.

---

I am having trouble with these questions about closed forms, could someone walk me step by step through each problem?  Thanks!

Comment: I mean... if you can translate them into characteristic equations, there's almost nothing left to do. Find the roots; this tells you the form that it must take, with a small set of unknowns; use the initial conditions to solve for the unknowns.  Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: You've posted several, nearly identical questions...none of which show any effort at all.  Are we just doing your homework for you?  What goes wrong when you use the characteristic equation method?

Comment: In particular, the accepted solution to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942779/recursion-finding-a-closed-form-2) of yours can be adapted to the different initial conditions.

Comment: @lulu  The solution to my previous problem was built on the fact that the closed form was an exponent, and it didn't include what to do if it wasn't an exponent.

Comment: The accepted solution to [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942779/recursion-finding-a-closed-form-2) contains the general formula, which applies to these problems as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first,  begin by solving the characteristic equation
$r^2-6r+9=0$

which has a double solution 3

so

$S_n=(an+b)3^n$

find a and b using initial conditions

$S_0$  and  $S_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
For you first problem you could rewrite it as a matrix equation
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
s_n\\
s_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
6s_{n-1}-9s_{n-2}\\
s_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
6 &-9\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
s_{n-1}\\
s_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
6 &-9\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
s_{1}\\
s_{0}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Thus, to find the closed form of $s_n$ it suffices to compute the $n-1$ power of your matrix.